# Difference between single and double quotes in awk

Tags: bash, awk, quotes

I have this `awk` statement:

```
glb_library="my_library"
awk "
        /^Direct Dependers of/ { next }
        /^---/                 { next }
        /^$glb_library:/       { ver=\$0; next }
                               { gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '', \$0); print ver':'\$0 }
      " file
```

Basically, I have enclosed the `awk` code in double quotes so that the shell variable `glb_library` is expanded.  I have made sure to escape the `$` character to prevent the shell from expanding `$0`. Followed the guidance from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

`awk` gives me this error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 5
 context is
                                   { gsub(/[[:space:]]/, >>>  ' <<<
```

I want to understand:

- Is it legal to use single quotes inside `awk`? Why is `''` not a null string like `""` is?
- Does `awk` treat single and double quotes differently?

My code worked after I escaped the single quotes with backslashes and used `\"\"` to represent the null string instead of `''`.

Comment: Do you know what the `-v` flag is for?

Comment: Yes, for passing variables to awk.

Comment: So why are you using it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Edited the question.

Comment: `awk` does not recognize single quotes.

Comment: You should use it and set `glb_library` as an awk variable to be used in the script, then you can put the whole thing in single quotes.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Do you have any documentation for that, like I know it doesn't but I've never seen it officially mentioned anywhere

Comment: This [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) talks about `''` being the null string in `awk`, but doesn't say `awk` doesn't recognize single quotes.

Comment: **single quote is not special within double quotes** and treated like any other non-special character

Comment: @WilliamPursell that's not true, awk recognizes single quotes just fine.

Comment: @123 awk recognizes single quotes just fine, the confusion you're having is that **the shell** does not allow single quotes within a single-quote delimited script. That applies whether the script is awk, sed, perl or anything else. If you for some reason **need** to have an explicit single quote within an awk script then just store it in a file and execute it as `awk -f script` so the shell rule doesn't get in the way and awk will have no trouble with the single quotes but in general use the octal escape sequence `\047` anywhere you need a single quote and it'll work from shell or in a file.

Comment: @EdMorton The POSIX specification for `awk` only specifies double quotes for string literals, and something as simple as `awk "END {print 'foo'}" < /dev/null` fails with both GNU `awk` 4.0.2 and BSD `awk` 20070501 (that ships with Mac OS X). What version of `awk` are you using that supports single-quoted strings?

Comment: @EdMorton That isn't the confusion I am having as I was already using a script to eliminate any possible shell influence. I know that you can use literal `'` in strings/regex, but in all awk versions I have ever used you cannot use single quotes to quote strings. If you run the script in  you get `awk: script.awk:3:           ^ invalid char ''' in expression`, and also the man page states `It is written in awk programs like this: "". In the shell, it can be written using single or double quotes: "" or ''` which would imply single quotes cannot be used.

Comment: @chepner I didn't say that `'` was a string delimiter in awk, it's not. The string delimiter in awk is `"`. What I said is that the statement `awk does not recognize single quotes` is not true - awk recognizes single quotes just fine.

Comment: @123 right `'` is not the string delimiter in awk, `"` is. The comment William made and you replied to was `awk does not recognize single quotes` which isn't true and is what my comments are also in response to. It never occurred to me he might just mean `... as a string delimiter` and idk if that IS what he meant or if, as I thought, he (and subsequently you) were referring to the more general and frequently misunderstood problem of trying to use single quotes in a single-quote delimited script.

Comment: I meant that awk does not recognize single quotes as a string delimiter, but I think it actually stands as a factually correct statement.  Other than inside a double quoted string, a single quote character is, as far as I know, always a syntax error.  If it is inside a double quoted string, I think it is correct to say that awk is not recognizing it, as it really doesn't "recognize" anything inside a string in any meaningful sense.  Are there any examples where a single quote can be used outside of a string literal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments above by awk experts and some research, I am posting this answer:

- awk strings are enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes; more precisely: ***single quotes are not string delimiters in awk, unlike shell***
- awk attaches no special meaning to single quotes and they need to be enclosed in double quotes if used in string literals
- it is best to use single quotes to wrap awk statements on command line, unlike OP's code that's using double quotes (Ed pointed this out clearly)

Further clarification:

- `""` is the null string in awk, not `''`
- to use single quotes in an awk string literal, enclose them in double quotes, as in `"Ed's answers are great!"`
- other techniques followed while handling single quotes in awk are:

  a) use a variable, as in `awk -v q="'" '{ print q }' ...`

  b) use octal or hex notation, as in `awk '{ print "\047"$0"\047" }' ...`

---

Relevant documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).

Comment: "awk treats single quotes as special characters" is misleading: it is precisely the fact that `'` has _no_ special meaning that precludes its use as a string delimiter. Demonstrating the use of `'` inside an _Awk_ double-quoted string is somewhat of a moot point, given that literal use of `'` is _impossible_ if the script is enclosed in `'...'` _as a whole_ - which is the only sensible choice.

Comment: I didn't use the term "special character" to mean "special meaning".  Just reworded the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Never enclose any script in double quotes or you're sentencing yourself to backslash-hell. This is the syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
glb_library="my_library"
awk -v glb_library="$glb_library" '
        /^Direct Dependers of/ { next }
        /^---/                 { next }
        $0 ~ "^"glb_library":" { ver=$0; next }
                               { gsub(/[[:space:]]/, ""); print ver":"$0 }
      ' file
```

Comment: Is `''` a valid null string in `awk` then?

Comment: No, the string delimiter in awk is `"`, not `'`, so a null string is `""`

Answer (score 7):

A pragmatic summary:

- As [Ed Morton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446993/45375) sensibly recommends:
  **Always use *single* quotes to enclose your `awk` *script as a whole* (`'...'`)**, which ensures that there's no confusion over what the *shell* interprets *up front*, and what `awk` ends up seeing.
- To **define strings *inside* an `awk` script, *always* use *double* quotes (`"..."`)**.

  - `"` is the only string delimiter `awk` recognizes.
  - `"..."` strings are *non-interpolating* (you cannot embed variable references), but they do recognize *control-character sequences* such as `\n` and `\t`.
- **A single quote (`'`) has no *syntactic* meaning inside an `awk` script**, but, - if you're using `'...'` for your overall script, as recommended - **you cannot use a literal `'` *inside of it anyway***, because the *shell's* single-quoted strings do not permit *embedded* `'` chars.

  - **If you *do* need to use a *literal* single quote (`'`) in your `awk` script**, you have three choices:

    - Pass a *variable* that defines it, and use `awk`'s string concatenation, based on directly adjoining string literals and variable references:
      `awk -v q=\' 'BEGIN { print "I" q "m good." }' # -> I'm good`
    - Use an *escape sequence* inside `"..."`; for maximum portability and disambiguation, use an *octal* escape sequence (`\047`), not a *hex* one (`\x27`):
      `awk 'BEGIN { print "I\047m good." }' # -> I'm good`
    - Use `'\''` (sic) to "escape" embedded `'` chars. (technically, 3 distinct single-quoted *shell* string literals are being concatenated)<sup>Thanks, [snr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990642/snr)</sup>:
      `awk 'BEGIN { print "I'\''m good" }' # -> I'm good`