# Error while using multiple quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quotes

I have written:

```
ssh $ip_address "grep -i 20-10-2018 | awk -F "," '{print $2",""open_"$5}' result.csv" | while read line
do
        echo $Date":00:00",$line
done
```

This is throwing this error:

> awk: {print ,open_} awk:        ^ syntax error

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you expect this script is doing?

Comment: If you tell us your samples input and output we could help you more in it, please add them in your post with CODE TAGS {} button.

Comment: I want to grep for a particular date in result.csv file and print it @ RavinderSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a heredoc to [run your commands over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412338/6862601):

```
ssh "$ip_address" << 'EOF'                 # shell will pass the heredoc as is to ssh because the end marker EOF is in quotes
    grep -i 20-10-2018 result.csv |        # I guess you meant to pass result.csv to grep, rather than awk
    awk -F "," '{ print $2",open_"$5 }' |  # good to put the parts of the pipeline on different lines for better readability
    while read line; do
      echo $Date":00:00",$line             # not sure what you mean by $Date here - probably $(date)?
    done
EOF
```

I am not sure what you mean by `echo $Date":00:00"`.  I left that part intact.

---

See this post to understand how to quote awk commands:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469079/6862601)

Another useful post about using quotes in shell:

- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104627/6862601)

Comment: Thank you . It is useful

Answer (score 0):

You write double quotes inside the single quotes that is wrong. Any code write first double quotes after inside single quotes.