# Escaping nested double quotes in awk

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, printf, quotes

In a Windows Server environment, having trouble with escaping quotes that are within quotes.  Using the functioning batch code below as a base:

```
awk -F "|" "$4 ~ /JUVENILE/ {sum +=$6} END {printf sum}" sourcedata.file
```

Problems occur when trying to include `"%.3f"` to printf.  I am confused and unable to properly escape these quotes in my environment.

```
awk -F "|" "$4 ~ /JUVENILE/ {sum +=$6} END {printf """%.3f""", sum}" sourcedata.file
```

The above *will* work at the command prompt, but *will not* work in a simple batch file. I have also attempted to replace `"%.3f"`  with `\"%.3f\"` and `\""%.3f\""` and these also do not work in a batch file.

Comment: I have forgotten Windows quoting, but in Unix you can use `'` on the outside of the program and then freely use `"` inside the script. Try this. So your script becomes `'$4 ~ /JUVENILE/ {sum +=$6} END {printf "%.3f", sum}'`

Comment: If you include the arguments in the batch file or on the command line you will need to double the percent symbol because it is used for variable expansion.

Comment: You could use single quotes here: `awk -F '|' '$4 ~ /JUVENILE/ {sum +=$6} END {printf "%.3f", sum} sourcedata.file`.  See [Difference between single and double quotes in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445852/6862601).  Just realized @dawg said this as well.
`

Comment: Folks - the OP is on Windows, not UNIX, so she's stuck with using double quotes for a command-line script.

Comment: The quotation should not be the problem, but the `%` sign which needs to be doubled in a batch file... if quotation does cause trouble, have you tried `'%.3f'`?

Comment: It was in fact the single percent symbol, and not the neighboring quote, causing this error.  Changed that snippet to `{printf \"%%.3f\", sum}`.  Thanks @Squashman @aschipfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard advice for Windows to avoid their nightmarish quoting rules is:

a) Don't call the script from Windows. Install cygwin or similar to get a UNIX-like environment and then call the script from that, or...

b) Don't specify the script text on the command line in Windows, save it in a file instead, i.e. put this in a file named `foo.awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS="|" }
$4 ~ /JUVENILE/ {sum +=$6}
END {printf "%.3f", sum}
```

and then execute it as `awk -f foo.awk sourcedata.file`

Comment: My particular error, in this case, was the result of the character next to the nested quote. I have had several issues with nested quotes, and did test with this methodology with success.  Will use in the future; thanks!